# Which are the realictic enviroment will be suitable for TDLC300 channel model?

Tags: fading-channel, lte, channel

TR 38.901 Section 7.7.2 mentioned that the TDL-A, TDL-B, and TDL-C channel models are constructed for NLOS scenarios. In TS 38.101-4 Annex B.2.1, in Table B.2.1.1-1 (picture is attached), delay profiles for NR channel models are mentioned where TDLA300 corresponds to 12 taps and 300 ns delay spread.

My question is -- we know the fundamental premise that TDL types A, C, and C are for NLOS propagation, apart from that can we also map TDLA300 to some particular channel environment, for example, urban macro, urban micro, rural, etc?

As of now, my current interest is TDLA300 but as a whole, I would like to map TDLA30, TDLB100, and TDLC300 to some particular environment.

It would be great if you could[image] help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, think about it. In 2595 ns, light travels ca 800 m, and a delay spread of 300 ns corresponds to a distance spread of 90 m. You can achieve that already between a transmitter and two large buildings which reflect "in your direction".

So, I don't know a name for this, but it could happen in cities, or in industrial settings, or where there's a farm and a silo, or even due to mountainous terrain.

Does the name really matter? This seems to be a reasonable setting, and your system has to deal with its numbers, not its nomenclature.